# Spring data doesnt pick correct alias to sort with pageable result

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Assume that i have below method in `EmployeeRepository` that extended `JpaRepository`:

```
@Query(value =
        "    select new com.my.EmployeeDTO(t.id, " +
        "       t.fullName, " +
        "       t.nationalCode, " +
        "       (select a.unit.code from UnitEmployee a where a.employee.id = t.id and a.isDefault = true)) " +
        "  from Employee t ",
countQuery =
        "select count(t.id) " +
        "  from Employee t ")
Page<EmployeeDTO> find(Pageable page);
```

and call it in service like this:

```
public Page<EmployeeDTO> findEmployee(EmployeeExample employeeExample) {
    EmployeeDTO employeeDTO = employeeExample.getExample();

    return employeeRepository.find(
            PageRequest.of(employeeExample.getPage(),
                    employeeExample.getSize(),
                    employeeExample.getSortDirection() == SortDirection.DESC ? Sort.Direction.DESC : Sort.Direction.ASC,
                    "t.id"
            ));
}
```

The problem is that spring data or maybe hibernate use `a` as alias and add `order by a.id desc` and picked it from sub query in select.

How can i specify correct alias?

Comment: Why the alias in there? Remove the `t.` part, you want to sort by `id`. Your service shouldn't know about the structure of your query.

Comment: I removed `"t.id"` from service and replaced it with `"id"`, but didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

As it is stated in the JPA 2.2 specification (see *4.6.16 Subqueries* section):

> Subqueries are restricted to the `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses in this release. Support for subqueries in the `FROM` clause will be considered in a later release of this specification.

So, your query is just not valid JPQL.
But you can try to rewrite your query in the following way:

```java
@Query(value =
        "    select new com.my.EmployeeDTO(t.id, " +
        "       t.fullName, " +
        "       t.nationalCode, " +
        "       a.unit.code) " +
        "  from Employee t, UnitEmployee a  where a.employee.id = t.id and a.isDefault = true",
countQuery = "select count(t.id) from Employee t ")
Page<EmployeeDTO> find(Pageable page);
```

or try to use hibernate [@Formula](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-formula) annotation.

Comment: I have exact same problem. But I do have subquery in where clause. e.g. `SELECT E FROM Employee E WHERE E.empId IN (SELECT EL.empId FROM EmployeeLeave EL WHERE EL.startDate >= '2022-01-01')` but the sorting by name is trying to sort by `EL.name`, when it should be E.name (or no alias at all)